# How to deal with iteration/looping in Python behave or BDD Scenarios in general?

Tags: python, loops, iteration, gherkin, python-behave

I am trying to use Python's [behave library](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/index.html) for writing some BDD/Gherkin style tests on a bunch of delimited textfiles.

A typical scenario would look like this:

```
Scenario: Check delivery files for illegal values
    Given a file system path to the delivery folder
    When I open each file and read its values
    Then all values in the "foo" column are smaller than 1
    And all values in the "fizz" column are larger than 2
```

Since there are lots of files and each file contains lots of rows, there is no possibility to hardcode all of them into Scenario Outlines. Moreover, I would like to avoid reading whole files into memory at once but rather use generators to iterate over the rows one by one.

I tried the following. However, this is very inefficient on large datasets and large amounts of conditions since each line is read again and again for every `then` step. Is there any possibility to pass a single row between multiple `then` steps and start again at the first `then` step for the next row?

Or is BDD/Gherkin not suited for this kind of testing? What could be an alternative?

```
import csv
import itertools
import os

@given('a file system path to the delivery folder')
def step(context):
    context.path = '/path/to/delivery/files'

@when('I open each file and read its values')
def step(context):

    file_list = os.listdir(context.path)

    def row_generator():
        for path in file_list:
            with open(path, 'rb') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:
                    yield row

    context.row_generator = row_generator

# itertools.tee forks off the row generator so it can be used multiple times instead of being exhausted after the first 'then' step

@then('all values in the "foo" column are smaller than 1')
def step(context):
    for row in itertools.tee(context.row_generator(), 1)[0]:
        assert row['foo'] < 1

@then('all values in the "bar" column are larger than 2')
def step(context):
    for row in itertools.tee(context.row_generator(), 1)[0]:
        assert row['bar'] > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirk, you could consider writing a script to generate the scenario outline (given the csv file).  That way you can rely on standard behave/gherkin features. Keep it as simple as possible as it introduces another place where things can go wrong. It however simplifies your step file so you can focus on the actual functional test rather than the mechanics of reading the csv file. Depending on how large your datasets are, you might also run into memory limitations as I presume the table is kept in memory only. Not a great solution, but 'an alternative'.

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve general looping of my scenarios - I have done it like below. Of course you'll have to write the step definition which could be as simple as having a log entry.

```
@test
Scenario Outline: Repeat Step in Loop
 Given we repeat the same test X times
 When we do something
 Then we analyze results
 Examples: Iteration
  | X |
  | 1 |
  | 2 |
  | 3 |
```

Thoughts welcome for a better way. The iterations are not programmatic and have to to hard coded (small script to generate that Examples table)

Comment: The OP wrote in the question: "Since there are lots of files and each file contains lots of rows, **there is no possibility to hardcode all of them into Scenario Outlines**." (Emphasis added.)